# How to Find number of occurances of words in a String Paragraph, using Pointers in C++ Pgm in a single iteration?

Tags: c++, pointers

suppose I have following paragraph of strings.
"A tape suggests the crew of the Costa Concordia ship mentioned only a "blackout" in a communication with Italian officials after hitting rocks.A tape suggests the crew of the Costa Concordia ship mentioned only a "blackout" in a communication with Italian officials after hitting rocks."

Now I have to write a C++ pgm which in single traversal gives the output like 
A 2
tape 2
suggests 2
the 2
......... and so on.

Note: Only one iteration, NO LOOP. using pointers.

Comment: You should tell us what you have tried, and with what part specifically you are having problems. Your question should involve code.

Comment: Sorry but what is pgm ? Is it "program" ?

Comment: I don't write this pgm thing, I only write programs.

Comment: @FORALL: pgm is short form of PROGRAM.

Comment: @GaryBuyn: I want help in logic, when it comes to use only on ITERATION.

Comment: @FORALL: I thought for the logic that, I will make a temporary dynamic array, which will store all the words which are already not present there in Array, if it is present then we will increase the counter. But this logic consists One Loop and inside that Multiple Loops.

Comment: iteration implies a looping construct, but you also say no loop?

Comment: Perhaps "single traversal" and "NO LOOP" means that you shouldn't count how many times the first word occurs, and then how many times the second word occurs, etc, resulting in multiple traversals of the string. That would be highly inefficient anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As you traverse the text, keep a record of what words you've seen so far and how many times you've seen each.

Then, when you've finished, print out the results.

Comment: A `std::map<std::string, int>` should do the trick for recording the number of occurances of each word.

Answer (score 0):

You must show us what you wrote yet.
If you are stuck, and assuming you have to write in C ( you spoke about pointer ), take a look at

- [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) -- Split string into tokens

The operation would then be linear with a hash table ( n call to strtok, ~O(1) access to the hash at each iteration, plus ~O(1) insertion if the word does not exist).
Hash table can be tricky to write in full C (but you can look at prefix tree for example). You can use [libc hash table](http://linux.die.net/man/3/hsearch), or if it is an option, use c++ [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/).